# can I put network process and database process together under the same method in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

see the code below, I put network request and local database write operation together under the same method.

```
ConcurrentAsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Pair<String, String> rlt = null;
            try {
                rlt = sc.createNewDir(repoID, parentDir, dirName);
            } catch (SeafException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String newDirID = rlt.first;
            String response = rlt.second;

            // The response is the dirents of the parentDir after creating
            // the new dir. We save it to avoid request it again
            mDatabaseHelper.saveDirents(repoID, parentDir, newDirID, response);
        }
    });
```

`sc.createNewDir()` was used to request network request and `mDatabaseHelper.saveDirents()` was used to write data into database.
I wonder if it breaks the programming rules of AsyncTask.
Waiting for your advice, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with running different background operations in a single AsyncTask, especially when these operations are logically connected - as in your case network operation produces input for database operations, also you always want to store network operation result to database.

Comment: you are right, and I tested the code on my photo, turned fine.